# Improving performance of Ruby socket programming

Tags: performance, ruby, socket

Server:

```
require 'socket'
require 'time'
require 'ap'

server = TCPServer.open(1026)

def process_the_request req, client # not important, disk-related process
  sleep 2
  req.to_s + ' ' + client.peeraddr[3].to_s + ' ' + Time.now.to_s
end

loop do

  Thread.start(server.accept) do |client|

    request = ''
    ch = ''

    begin 

      ch = client.getc
      print ch

      if (ch.nil? or ch.ord == 13 or ch.ord == 10)

        if request.length < 1
          break if client.eof?
          next
        end

        ap "request: " + request
        response = process_the_request request, client
        ap "response: " + response
        client.puts response
        request = ''
        break if client.eof?

      else
        request += ch
      end


    end while true

    #ap "thread closed" 
    client.close

  end # Thread

end # loop
```

Client:

```
nn='nc 127.0.0.1 1026'
echo -n '1' | $nn &
echo '2' | $nn &
echo -n '3' | $nn &
echo '4
5
6
7' | $nn &
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't read from the client one byte at a time.  Call [`client.gets`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/socket/rdoc/TCPSocket.html) to take a line at a time.

Comment: somehow client.gets not working when client breaks (e.g. when they forgot to send \n on the last line), i ended up running too many unfinished thread